# Integrate aws-cli via docker to the linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, docker

In order not to have too many local installations, I decided to encapsulate the aws and kubectl cli's to a docker container and integrate it via this script, which is accessible on the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
VERSION=0.9
AWS_DIR=~/.aws
KUBE_DIR=~/.kube

if [[ "$1" == "build" ]]; then
    CONTAINER=awsclibuild
   docker run -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro --name=${CONTAINER} -itd -e http_proxy -e https_proxy -e no_proxy --net=host ubuntu:jammy sleep infinity

   #Install aws cli
   docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip less"
   docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c "curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip"
   docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c "unzip awscliv2.zip"
   docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c "./aws/install"

    #install kubectl cli
    docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c 'curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'
    docker exec -it $CONTAINER bash -c "install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl"


   docker stop $CONTAINER
   docker commit $CONTAINER awskubectl:$VERSION
   docker rm -f $CONTAINER
   exit 0
fi


docker run -it --rm \
    -e http_proxy -e https_proxy -e no_proxy -e AWS_PROFILE \
    --net=host \
    -v /mnt/c:/mnt/c \
    -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
    -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube \
    -v "$(pwd)":/userworkdir \
    -w /userworkdir \
    awskubectl:$VERSION bash -c "$*"
```

This works for most cases, what is not working is e.g. piping the output to grep.

So for example if I do this:

```
 aws iam list-roles
```

it perfectly opens the less and I can browse.

But if I do this:

```
 aws iam list-roles | grep "something"
```

it just ends up in not displaying anything, but returns when I press "q". So I suppose the pipe is not prpagated to the docker container. This then just uses the default "less" of course.

Dou you have an idea how I could integrate this to the command line better

Comment: Meanwhile I removed -it from the docker run command, which at least makes it possible to pipe the outputs, but also avoids the "black magic" that aws-cli is doing to decide if the output is passed to less or to stdout.